# Issue in qhull.cpython-38-darwin.so while importing sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, qhull

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling sklearn, scipy, numpy, anaconda3 and nothing resolved this issue. Provided the code and Error message below

**Code :**

`from sklearn import svm,datasets`

**Error Summary**

`ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): bad rebase type 0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/spatial/../.dylibs/libopenblas.0.dylib`

**All Error :**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f79259517934> in <module>
      1 # Import libraries and packages
      2 # import sklearn
----> 3 from sklearn import svm,datasets
      4 import pickle
      5 import numpy as np

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>
     78     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     79     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 80     from .base import clone
     81     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     82 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <module>
     19 from . import __version__
     20 from ._config import get_config
---> 21 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     22 from .utils.validation import check_X_y
     23 from .utils.validation import check_array

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>
     21 
     22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 23 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
     24 from . import _joblib
     25 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
      8 
      9 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in <module>
     24 from contextlib import suppress
     25 
---> 26 from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan
     27 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     28 from ..exceptions import NonBLASDotWarning, PositiveSpectrumWarning

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py in <module>
     16 import scipy.sparse as sp
     17 import scipy
---> 18 import scipy.stats
     19 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     20 from numpy.ma import MaskedArray as _MaskedArray  # TODO: remove in 0.25

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py in <module>
    439 ""
    440 
--> 441 from .stats import *
    442 from .distributions import *
    443 from .morestats import *

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in <module>
     35 from numpy import array, asarray, ma
     36 
---> 37 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
     38 from scipy.ndimage import measurements
     39 from scipy._lib._util import (check_random_state, MapWrapper,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py in <module>
     96 from .kdtree import *
     97 from .ckdtree import *
---> 98 from .qhull import *
     99 from ._spherical_voronoi import SphericalVoronoi
    100 from ._plotutils import *

ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): bad rebase type 0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/spatial/../.dylibs/libopenblas.0.dylib
```